# How does academia handle those with test anxieties?

Tags: exams, disability

Suppose you truly know the material but cannot perform well in a testing setting because you have real diagnosed anxiety or testophobia. How is it accommodated?

I was considering this for someone who has to take the qualifying exams as well.

So how do professors and administrators handle testophobia/test anxiety?

Comment: I am looking forward to the answers to this, but I am afraid for many institutions the real answer to your titular question may be "very poorly".

Comment: You should have some rights under ADA if you’re in the US.

Comment: It may be good to clarify your question: are you interested in what is actually done (which is the title question) or in what you could do to accomodate such student ?

Comment: yes, what can be done to accommodate for a student?

Comment: I dealt with this very thing by learning to fight it myself. This has benefited me from time to time throughout life. It's great if there's someone to come to your aid, at least for the short term. Even better is acquiring a new skill that will serve you for a lifetime, at times when there's no one to help.

Comment: The accommodations for someone with unnatural anxiety should greatly depend on where you study. While some universities have well-established procedures for dealing with it, in North America in particular, others will generally make no exceptions and expect their students to deal with their problems themselves. Please make sure not to give your friend a false sense of security if the options mentioned in the answers are unavailable at their university.

Answer (score 31):

There are several options, applied as they wish by the institutions.

These include (not an exhaustive list as based on experience from places I have been):

1) extra time ie 20% or more longer.

2) separate room - fewer people ie quieter.

3) a « coach » does not provide answers but helps student « think » and structure response.

4) a scribe, who writes the answer but does not provide the answer, just transcribes the words of the student.

5) providing "oral" based exams ie questions prepared to read to the student and responses written for the student.

The choice of strategy depends on an assessment of the student. This assessment is usually completed by a "Student Learning Officer" or equivalent, who can assess the student’s learning impairment & needs and decide accordingly.

Some of these require a huge effort for implementation ie option 5 means the professor gets to write a unique exam which takes a lot of time...

Comment: Interesting. I have not heard of option (3) so far. I like the thought, but that solution seems like it will be extremely difficult to implement fairly.

Comment: @xLeitix well, seen it as the student starts mentioning things relevant, so the coach says put them on a bubble diagram and link them etc... So, the student starts to build a useful response... It is based on the input from the student, just getting them to use it...

Comment: 3) We sometimes do this with students on the autistic spectrum. You can use a helper from a different field if you are worried about interference. There are students who literally will not put pen to paper if you don't tell them.

Comment: http://jaapl.org/content/jaapl/25/2/197.full.pdf

Comment: wow, I had no idea that there were way many more options for these people! Great answer.